# Menu selection and calling methods

Tags: java

Hey Guys have written a program that consists of a service menu, exactly like a bank card.
The problem is i have used a method called doLogin and used a boolean value so as that if the answer == true is will doServiceMenu else if it's false i want it keep getting the doLogin.

However this isn't working and I'm not sure if it's my Logic, any feed back would be greatly appreciated

```
`enter code here`import java.util.Scanner;
class TopUp{

    //class variable
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    static String name = "Joe";
    static String cardNumber = "1234 5678 9101 1213";
    static double balance = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean isLoginCorrect = false;
         isLoginCorrect =  doLogin();

    if(isLoginCorrect == true){
        doServiceMenu();
    }
    else if(isLoginCorrect == false){
             System.out.println("Incorrect username or password,try again!");
             System.out.println();
             doLogin();
     }
   }

   public static boolean doLogin(){

    String userName = "joe" ;
    String password = "123456";
    String nameInput;
    String pwdInput;



    System.out.println("Please enter your Username: ");
     nameInput = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter your Password: ");
     pwdInput = scan.nextLine();

    return ((userName.equals(nameInput)) && (password.equals(pwdInput)));

   }

   public static void doServiceMenu(){

    System.out.println("<********************* Services Menu ****************>");
    System.out.println("<**************  Please Select an option: ***********>");
    System.out.println("1> Customer Details");
    System.out.println("2> Customer Balance");
    System.out.println("3> Top-up");
    System.out.println("4> Make A Purchase");
    System.out.println("5> Quit");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("<*************************************************>");

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String menuSelect = keyboard.nextLine();

        switch (menuSelect) {

           case "1":
                    showCustomerDetails();
                    checkIfUserWantsAnotherTransaction();
                    break;
           case "2":

                    printBalance();
                    checkIfUserWantsAnotherTransaction();
                    break;
           case "3":
                    doTopUp();
                    checkIfUserWantsAnotherTransaction();
                    break;
           case "4":
                    makePurchase();
                    checkIfUserWantsAnotherTransaction();
                    break;
           case "5":
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!!!");
                    break;
           default:
                   System.err.println ( "Unrecognized option" );
                   break;
           }
        }

    public static void showCustomerDetails(){
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Card Number : " + cardNumber);
    }

    public static void printBalance(){
        System.out.println("Your balance is : " + balance);
    }

    public static void increaseBalance(double amount){
        balance += amount;
    }

    public static void decreaseBalance(double amount){
        balance -= amount;
    }


    public static void doTopUp(){
        System.out.println("Please enter a Top Up Amount: ");
    double amount = scan.nextDouble();
    double maxTopUp = 1000 - balance;

   if(amount > maxTopUp){
       System.out.println("Amount exceedes Max Top Up: ");
   }
   else{
        increaseBalance(amount);
        printBalance();
   }
}

    public static void makePurchase(){
        System.out.println("Please enter the purchase amount: ");
    double amount = scan.nextDouble();
    double purchase = amount - balance;

    if(amount > balance){
       System.out.println("Sorry Insufficent Funds: ");
    }
    else{
         decreaseBalance(amount);
         printBalance();
    }
  }

    public static void checkIfUserWantsAnotherTransaction() {
        System.out.println("Would you Like another Service: y/n");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String option = keyboard.nextLine();

     if(option.equals("y")){
         doServiceMenu();
     }
     else if(option.equals("n")){
              System.out.println("Goodbye!!!");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Be careful when using `nextLine` after `nextXXX`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what bank cards have service menus?

Answer (score 0):

If they fail the login the first time, the program enters this block:

```
else if(isLoginCorrect == false){
         System.out.println("Incorrect username or password,try again!");
         System.out.println();
         doLogin();
}
```

At the end of that block, the program exits (regardless of whether login was successful or not). You need to introduce a loop around doLogin(), and when it finally succeeds, call the `doServiceMenu()` function.

I would implement something like this:

```
while(doLogin() != true) {
    System.out.println("Incorrect username or password,try again!");
}
doServiceMenu();
```

Comment: Thanks vipw that does same sense, shoud i use a for loop something like for(i = 0; = 0; i++)  (i know this loop doesn't make sense) i'am just not sure how the loop calls the doLogin ?

Comment: @user3006218 I've updated my answer with a way to continually retry login until it's successful. You might want to use a for loop to limit the number of failed attempts (a good learning exercise).

Comment: Sweet!! Thanks vipw got the program to run fine thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a compile error, the follwoing might not work in your code:

```
 String menuSelect = keyboard.nextLine();
 switch (menuSelect) { 
     ...
 }
```

You can not switch over a String value. You can only switch over int or Enums. So you should convert your String into in int first.

Like that:

```
int menuSelect = Integer.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine());

    switch (menuSelect) {

       case 1:
            ...

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this inside your `main`:

```
boolean isLoginCorrect = false;
int maxAttempt = 5;

for (int loginAttempt = 1; (isLoginCorrect) || (loginAttempt > maxAttempt); loginAttempt++)
{
    isLoginCorrect = doLogin();
    if ((!isLoginCorrect) && (loginAttempt < maxAttempt))
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect username or password,try again!");
        System.out.println();
    }
}

if(isLoginCorrect == true){
    doServiceMenu();
}
```

Comment: Hey Lajos thanks for your reply tried the code but keep getting an illegal start of an expression on doLogin

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code as it is right now (including my suggestion)? Also, can you pay more attention to tabulation in your code from now on?